# OpenCL libraries and bindings

Tags: java, c++, opengl, d, opencl

Does anybody know any libraries of CL-procedures (it will be better if there is a good documentation)?

And Im also interested in D-languages binding.

Has somebody seen benchmarks that compares performance of native code applications with OpenCL and/or OpenGL and performance of [Java Binding](http://jogamp.org/)? I know that DLL calls cause of performance decline. Does an application written on C/C++ will be anyway faster than the same on Java?

Comment: You can find D bindings and a wrapper library at: https://github.com/Trass3r/cl4d

Comment: Are you an author of this binding?

Comment: I want to talk with him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jakob already said, my D wrapper is @ https://github.com/Trass3r/cl4d

With inlining, -version=NO_CL_EXCEPTIONS and proper dead code elimination the code should be nearly equivalent to a manually coded app using the C API directly.

So the wrapper introduces almost no overhead, performance depends on your kernels and clever memory transport.

Answer (score 1):

How about [JavaCL](http://code.google.com/p/javacl/) which works for me ?

As far as I have seen the cost of binding is fairly small compared to other overheads such as compiling the CL code and exchanging data with the GPU.

Comment: FYI if you're looking after some basic util functions / CL-procedures, JavaCL ships with LibCL : https://github.com/ochafik/nativelibs4java/tree/master/libraries/OpenCL/LibCL/src/main/resources/LibCL